# Tools for memory leak detection in linux kernel modules

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I am writing the driver and I would like to know the tools which can be helpful for scanning/analyzing the memory leaks in the Linux kernel modules.

Comment: If you design your code right, the driver should do a minimal functionality, which would be very simple. If so, it should be easy to verify that there are no leaks, without any tools.

Answer (score 2):

I have used the [KEDR framework](https://github.com/euspectre/kedr/wiki) with some success here.

There is also [KMEMCHECK](http://kerneltrap.org/Linux/Debugging_With_kmemcheck), but I haven't used it so I can't vouch for it's ease of use.

Comment: I would also add [Kmemleak](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/kmemleak.txt) to the list of the tools worth trying. While KEDR is good for memory leak detection in a kernel module of your choice, Kmemleak could be handy in a system-wide analysis (the kernel proper and all loaded modules at once).

Comment: As for Kmemcheck, its goal is probably not to reveal memory leaks in the first place but to detect incorrect memory accesses (somewhat similar to what Valgrind's Memcheck does in user space). [The docs on Kmemcheck](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/kmemcheck.txt) provide more details and another usage example.

Comment: Concerning KEDR, if someone would like to use KEDR 0.3 for the kernel 3.3 or newer, the hints how to build it properly on such kernels are [here](http://code.google.com/p/kedr/issues/detail?id=5).